# Serializing Cart content without loosing data in WooCommerce 3

Tags: arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, woocommerce

I have a client who wants to re-route all the carts from his various WooCommerce stores to one cart. For example the carts from stores A, B, C, and D will be passed to store F's payment gateway.

I figured out a way to do this by taking the contents of a cart from any of the stores and passing that to the function that makes the order in WooCommerce, but I have a problem here because if I `var_dump` `WC()->cart->get_cart()` it returns this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    int(20)
    ["variation_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["variation"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["quantity"]=>
    int(2)
    ["line_total"]=>
    float(3001.98)
    ["line_subtotal"]=>
    float(3001.98)
    ["line_tax"]=>
    float(0)
    ["line_subtotal_tax"]=>
    float(0)
    ["line_tax_data"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["total"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["subtotal"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["data"]=>
    object(WC_Product_Simple)#8809 (12) {
      ["object_type":protected]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["post_type":protected]=>
      string(7) "product"
      ["cache_group":protected]=>
      string(8) "products"
      ["data":protected]=>
      array(48) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Jet sky"
        ["slug"]=>
        string(7) "jet-sky"
        ["date_created"]=>
        object(WC_DateTime)#8801 (4) {
          ["utc_offset":protected]=>
          int(0)
          ["date"]=>
          string(26) "2017-06-23 15:25:27.000000"
          ["timezone_type"]=>
          int(1)
          ["timezone"]=>
          string(6) "+00:00"
        }
        ["date_modified"]=>
        object(WC_DateTime)#8804 (4) {
          ["utc_offset":protected]=>
          int(0)
          ["date"]=>
          string(26) "2017-06-23 15:25:27.000000"
          ["timezone_type"]=>
          int(1)
          ["timezone"]=>
          string(6) "+00:00"
        }
        ["status"]=>
        string(7) "publish"
        ["featured"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["catalog_visibility"]=>
        string(7) "visible"
        ["description"]=>
        string(278) "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo."
        ["short_description"]=>
        string(93) "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."
        ["sku"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["price"]=>
        string(7) "1500.99"
        ["regular_price"]=>
        string(7) "1500.99"
        ["sale_price"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["date_on_sale_from"]=>
        NULL
        ["date_on_sale_to"]=>
        NULL
        ["total_sales"]=>
        int(0)
        ["tax_status"]=>
        string(7) "taxable"
        ["tax_class"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["manage_stock"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["stock_quantity"]=>
        NULL
        ["stock_status"]=>
        string(7) "instock"
        ["backorders"]=>
        string(2) "no"
        ["sold_individually"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["weight"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["length"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["width"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["height"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["upsell_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["cross_sell_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["parent_id"]=>
        int(0)
        ["reviews_allowed"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["purchase_note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["attributes"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["default_attributes"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["virtual"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["downloadable"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["category_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["tag_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["shipping_class_id"]=>
        int(0)
        ["downloads"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["image_id"]=>
        string(2) "18"
        ["gallery_image_ids"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          int(19)
        }
        ["download_limit"]=>
        int(-1)
        ["download_expiry"]=>
        int(-1)
        ["rating_counts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["average_rating"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["review_count"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      ["supports":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "ajax_add_to_cart"
      }
      ["id":protected]=>
      int(20)
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["object_read":protected]=>
      bool(true)
      ["extra_data":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["default_data":protected]=>
      array(48) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["slug"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["date_created"]=>
        NULL
        ["date_modified"]=>
        NULL
        ["status"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["featured"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["catalog_visibility"]=>
        string(7) "visible"
        ["description"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["short_description"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sku"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["price"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["regular_price"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sale_price"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["date_on_sale_from"]=>
        NULL
        ["date_on_sale_to"]=>
        NULL
        ["total_sales"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["tax_status"]=>
        string(7) "taxable"
        ["tax_class"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["manage_stock"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["stock_quantity"]=>
        NULL
        ["stock_status"]=>
        string(7) "instock"
        ["backorders"]=>
        string(2) "no"
        ["sold_individually"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["weight"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["length"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["width"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["height"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["upsell_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["cross_sell_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["parent_id"]=>
        int(0)
        ["reviews_allowed"]=>
        bool(true)
        ["purchase_note"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["attributes"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["default_attributes"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["menu_order"]=>
        int(0)
        ["virtual"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["downloadable"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["category_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["tag_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["shipping_class_id"]=>
        int(0)
        ["downloads"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["image_id"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["gallery_image_ids"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["download_limit"]=>
        int(-1)
        ["download_expiry"]=>
        int(-1)
        ["rating_counts"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["average_rating"]=>
        int(0)
        ["review_count"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      ["data_store":protected]=>
      object(WC_Data_Store)#8807 (4) {
        ["instance":"WC_Data_Store":private]=>
        object(WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT)#8806 (5) {
          ["internal_meta_keys":protected]=>
          array(39) {
            [0]=>
            string(11) "_visibility"
            [1]=>
            string(4) "_sku"
            [2]=>
            string(6) "_price"
            [3]=>
            string(14) "_regular_price"
            [4]=>
            string(11) "_sale_price"
            [5]=>
            string(22) "_sale_price_dates_from"
            [6]=>
            string(20) "_sale_price_dates_to"
            [7]=>
            string(11) "total_sales"
            [8]=>
            string(11) "_tax_status"
            [9]=>
            string(10) "_tax_class"
            [10]=>
            string(13) "_manage_stock"
            [11]=>
            string(6) "_stock"
            [12]=>
            string(13) "_stock_status"
            [13]=>
            string(11) "_backorders"
            [14]=>
            string(18) "_sold_individually"
            [15]=>
            string(7) "_weight"
            [16]=>
            string(7) "_length"
            [17]=>
            string(6) "_width"
            [18]=>
            string(7) "_height"
            [19]=>
            string(11) "_upsell_ids"
            [20]=>
            string(14) "_crosssell_ids"
            [21]=>
            string(14) "_purchase_note"
            [22]=>
            string(19) "_default_attributes"
            [23]=>
            string(19) "_product_attributes"
            [24]=>
            string(8) "_virtual"
            [25]=>
            string(13) "_downloadable"
            [26]=>
            string(9) "_featured"
            [27]=>
            string(19) "_downloadable_files"
            [28]=>
            string(16) "_wc_rating_count"
            [29]=>
            string(18) "_wc_average_rating"
            [30]=>
            string(16) "_wc_review_count"
            [31]=>
            string(22) "_variation_description"
            [32]=>
            string(13) "_thumbnail_id"
            [33]=>
            string(11) "_file_paths"
            [34]=>
            string(22) "_product_image_gallery"
            [35]=>
            string(16) "_product_version"
            [36]=>
            string(12) "_wp_old_slug"
            [37]=>
            string(10) "_edit_last"
            [38]=>
            string(10) "_edit_lock"
          }
          ["extra_data_saved":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["updated_props":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["meta_type":protected]=>
          string(4) "post"
          ["object_id_field_for_meta":protected]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        ["stores":"WC_Data_Store":private]=>
        array(18) {
          ["coupon"]=>
          string(24) "WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT"
          ["customer"]=>
          string(22) "WC_Customer_Data_Store"
          ["customer-download"]=>
          string(31) "WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store"
          ["customer-session"]=>
          string(30) "WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session"
          ["order"]=>
          string(23) "WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT"
          ["order-refund"]=>
          string(30) "WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT"
          ["order-item…
```

When I try to loop through it and store the serialized or encoded values, this is what I get:

```
{ ["98f13708210194c475687be6106a3b84"]=> array(10) 
{ ["product_id"]=> int(20) 
["variation_id"]=> int(0) 
["variation"]=> array(0) { } 
["quantity"]=> int(2) 
["line_total"]=> float(3001.98) 
["line_subtotal"]=> float(3001.98) 
["line_tax"]=> int(0) 
["line_subtotal_tax"]=> int(0) 
["line_tax_data"]=> array(2) {
 ["total"]=> array(0) { } 
["subtotal"]=> array(0) { } } 
["data"]=> array(0) { } } }`
```

**My questions:**

- What could be happening?
- Why do I lose so much data?
- How to get the missing data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loosing the `["data"]` because as you can see it's a **`WC_product`** object and you can access the data directly since woocommerce 3+.

*All other data after is protected so you can't get it too.*

So you need to use a foreach loop this way:

```
// iterating through each cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item_values ){

    // We set the cart item data in an array
    $wc_get_cart[$item_key] = $item_values;

    // We remove the WC_Product object from this array
    unset($wc_get_cart[$item_key]['data']);

    // We set the data with WC_Data get_data() method in a variable (array)
    $product_data = $item_values['data']->get_data();

    // We set back this data
    $wc_get_cart[$item_key]['data'] = $product_data;

}
```

Now you can serialize **`$wc_get_cart`** multi dimensional array and you will see that you have all the needed data

> So you can use [**`WC_Data get_data()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_data) method to convert WooCommerce objects like **Orders** or **Products** in an array and then to access properties without using the classes methods.

---